# Do I own a token that I create under somebody else's control?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was reading somewhere a few days ago that when a player creates a token using a spell like [Rapid Hybridization](http://magiccards.info/gtc/en/44.html) they own the token, even though they never had control of it. I can't seem to find the discussion or the relevant rule.

When I create a token that comes into play under another players control, do I own the token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, that token is owned by the other player.  From the current Comprehensive Rules:

> 110.5a A token is both owned and controlled by the player under whose control it entered the battlefield.

Tokens *used to be* owned by the controller of the effect that created them, but this was [changed in the Magic 2010 rules revision](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/42a) to line up better with people's intuitions about ownership of permanents.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I found the link and was about to make the same edit, but you beat me to it!

Comment: You beat me to posting the rules quote. Tit for tat. ;)

Comment: Looks like the way I always thought it worked has only been true since July of 2009. Thanks for posting all the rule changes for M10.

Comment: There used to be a bunch of decks that abused the old rules with Hunted creatures (e.g. Hunted Dragon, Hunted Phantasm) and Brand.  A neat idea, but not really in the true spirit of the cards :)

Comment: @thesunneversets I was making an EDH deck using Zedruu the Greathearted. This would have mattered quite a bit, but I wasn't going to make it abusive. I didn't even consider the amount of random things that could be done that would abuse that rule.

Comment: Lots of people who never read the M10 rules update very carefully tried to build that Zedruu deck when she was printed and were very disappointed :)